# How to replace an entire column without losing the formatting in awk

Tags: awk, replace

<sup>**Editor's note**:

This question has a troubled edit history in that a well-meaning, but misguided edit (which introduced unrelated, "pretty" formatting relying on spaces and `|` chars. to separate columns) temporarily confused the issue (since reverted).

The OP's premise is that the input is *tab*-delimited, even though that's not directly reflected in the sample input displayed here.</sup>

I have a input file having 6 columns and they are tab-separated. I want to replace all values in column 5 with value `'81115'`, while keeping the formatting intact.

Input File :

```
203           ADD              24       IAC              81216            IT     
204           ATT              24       IAC              81216            IT
```

Desired Output File :

```
203           ADD              24       IAC              81115            IT  
204           ATT              24       IAC              81115            IT
```

**My solution #1**

I am using the following command:

```
awk '{$5 = v} 1' v="81115" file > file.NEW
```

With the above command, column 5 is getting replaced, but the columns are no longer tab-separated.

Output File :

```
203 ADD 24 IAC 81115 IT 

204 ATT 24 IAC 81115 IT
```

**My solution #2**

To maintain the formatting I have tried using the following commands:

```
awk -v replace="81115" -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' {$5=replace}1' file > file.NEW
```

OR

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{$5=81115}1' file > file.NEW
```

OR

```
awk -F '\t' '{$5="81115";}1' OFS='\t' file > file.NEW
```

All of the above commands are keeping the formatting intact, but are adding a new column with value `81115` at the end; i.e., column 7 is getting appended.

Output File:

```
203           ADD              24       IAC              81216            IT            81115

204           ATT              24       IAC              81216            IT            81115
```

Can anyone suggest an alternate solution or changes to above commands?

Comment: Try : `awk -v new="81115" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} {$5=new}1' file`

Comment: All of your solution #2 versions work just fine over here. Solution #1 is fine also, just add `-v OFS="\t"` to it. I tested with MAWK and GAWK. Test that your input file really is tab delimited.

Comment: alternate.. `perl -pe 's/^(\S+\s+){4}\K\S+/81115/' file > file.NEW`.. or if 5th column is always `81216` and unique in the file, why not a simple `sed 's/81216/81115/' file > file.NEW`

Comment: As @JamesBrown wrote, all your solution #2 versions work in my RHEL box... Now, you missed a single quote in your `awk` command of solution #2.

Comment: Hang on - you say your fields are tab-separated but you show them separated by `|`s and spaces. Which is correct? If your sample input/output is intended to show us what your files WOULD look like in table format rather than your actual files - don't do that, show us the actual files, not some graphical representation of them. If those really are your actual files - where are the tabs you say separate the fields? If any of your solution 2 scripts are appending a field to the end of the line then it's because your input files **are not** tab separated.

Comment: @EdMorton:  Totally agree with you, the last question edit caused that. I originally updated the question to have tab-separation and rejected the one which is currently there, but somehow it got in. Refer this edit history http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39142140/revisions

Answer (score 1):

For in-column update retaining the format, you need to use the split function. Note that the split function with forth argument is supported only by GNU awk.

Try this:

```
 awk '{split($0, a, FS, seps)          # split based on FS
      a[5]="81115";                    # Update the 5th column
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)              # print the data back
         printf("%s%s", a[i], seps[i]) # keeping the separators
      print ""}'                       # print a new line
```

One-liner:

```
 awk '{split($0, a, FS, seps); a[5]="81115"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", a[i], seps[i]); print ""}' /tmp/data
```

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326264/2032943

Comment: ++, but please add a note stating that your solution requires _GNU_ `awk` (per POSIX, the `split()` function doesn't support the 4th argument, and neither Mawk nor BSD/macOS Awk support it).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note:

- If you must preserve the *exact* separator strings from the input *and* you have *GNU* `awk`, see [@Sundeep's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458395/45375), or, for a solution covering *all* fields, see [Jay Rajput's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456663/45375).

- *This* answers tries to diagnose the OP's problem and a contains a solution that converts the input to consistently tab-delimited output.</sup>

Your 1st attempt doesn't preserve tabs in the output, because, in the absence of setting `OFS`, the output-field separator, Awk separates *output* fields by a *space* each.
(By *assigning* to a field, as you do with `$5 = ...`, the input line is *implicitly rebuilt*, using the value of `OFS` (a space by default) as the separator to piece the (modified) fields back together to form the *output* line.)

Your other attempts all look reasonable, which suggests that **your input file may not be structured the way you think it is.**

Use `cat -et` to verify that all columns in your input file are indeed separated by a tab each: `^I` represents a tab in the output of `cat -et`.

If your input file contains a *mix* of tab- and space(s)-separated columns and/or if some fields have *multiple tabs* between them, **you need to rely on `awk`'s *default* parsing** to split your input into fields as expected, namely by *any run of nonempty whitespace*.
You then **use tab as the separator only *on output*, by setting `OFS` only**:

```
awk -v replace='81115' -v OFS='\t' '{$5=replace}1' file
```

Note the absence of the `-F` option so as to rely on Awk's default field-splitting behavior.

While this will not necessarily keep the exact input formatting, you will get *consistently* tab-separated output.

Comment: may be add `gensub` equivalent of `sed -E 's/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/\181115/' file`  to retain space formatting...

Comment: @Sundeep: `gensub` requires _GNU_ `awk`, and if you can use that, then @JayRajput's answer is the best approach.

Comment: I am not very familiar with syntax, but `awk '{$0 = gensub(/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/, "\\181115", "g", $0)}1' file` seems much simpler than using split

Comment: @Sundeep: Good point: Your solution is simpler and seems to work (except that I suggest using `"1"` instead of `"g"`). I encourage you to post this command as your own answer - but please state that the solution requires _GNU_ `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution based on given sample input is a simple search and replace using `sed`, which assumes 5th column has only same value of `81216` and that value doesn't occur anywhere in 1-4 column

```
$ sed 's/81216/81115/' file 
203           ADD              24       IAC              81115            IT     
204           ATT              24       IAC              81115            IT
```

If any value in 5th column has to be replaced,

```
sed -E 's/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/\181115/' file
```

If `\s` and `\S` are not recognized, use

```
sed -E 's/^(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4})[^[:space:]]+/\181115/' file
```

Similar solution can be used with `GNU awk` which has the `gensub` function

```
awk '{$0 = gensub(/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/, "\\181115", "1", $0)}1' file
```

Or with variable,

```
awk -v replace='81115' '{$0 = gensub(/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/, "\\1"replace, "1", $0)}1' file
```

All the above solutions preserve input file space formatting