# AWK: Is there a way to set OFS as FS if this one is a regex?

Tags: regex, awk

In awk, the field (or record) separator `FS` (or `RS`) can be set as a regular expression.
It works great for getting any individual field, but once you set one these fields, the field seperators are "gone".

```
echo "a|b-c|d" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|-]"} {$3="z"}1'
a b z d
```

In this case the output field separator `OFS` is per default set as a space.

Unfortunately this kind of statement `OFS=FS="[|-]"` is not working, because it sets `OFS` as a litteral string.

I understand that it might get tricky for awk to select the output field separator if there are several choices, but in case of no new fields, the current ones could remain.

So, is there an easy way to set `OFS` to be the exact same regex as `FS`, such that I get this?

```
echo "a|b-c|d" | awk '... {$3="z"}1'
a|b-z|d
```

Alternatively, is there a way to capture all separators, in a array for example?

The same question also applies to the record separator `RS` (and its associated `ORS`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned, there is no way to set `OFS` dynamically based on the `FS` that was used on every case. If the regex was in `RS` instead of `FS`, you could use `RT` (in fact, I just see anubhava's answer does this, nice!).

However, there is another way if you have GNU awk: as seen in [column replacement with awk, with retaining the format (Ed Morton's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211988/1983854), you can use [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) and, specially, its 4th argument. Why? Because it stores the separator between every slice:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[|-]"}                     # set FS
     {split($0, a, FS, seps)               # split based on FS and ...
                                           # ...  store pieces in the array seps()
      a[3]="z"                             # change the 3rd field
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                  # print the data back
           printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]    # keeping the separators
      print ""                             # print a new line
     }'
```

As one-liner:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[|-]"} {split($0, a, FS, seps); a[3]="z"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]; print ""}' <<< "a|b-c|d"
a|b-z|d
```

> **split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])**
>
> Divide string into pieces separated by fieldsep and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the seps array. The first piece is stored in array[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211988/1983854), the second piece in array[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), and so forth. The string value of the third argument, fieldsep, is a regexp describing where to split string (much as FS can be a regexp describing where to split input records). If fieldsep is omitted, the value of FS is used. split() returns the number of elements created. **seps is a gawk extension, with seps[i] being the separator string between array[i] and array[i+1]**. If fieldsep is a single space, then any leading whitespace goes into seps[0] and any trailing whitespace goes into seps[n], where n is the return value of split() (i.e., the number of elements in array).

Comment: Very good `split` based solution using `seps` as 4th argument. Hopefully OP has gnu awk.

Comment: I guess that there's no need to change `FS` here; you may as well just use `/[|-]/` as the third argument to `split`.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` rewrites each record using `OFS` if you change any filed value using `$N=<whatever>` (where N is field number).

Since you're using multiple delimiters in `FS` you cannot use `OFS=FS`.

If you have `gnu awk` then you can use `RS` and `RT` based solution:

```
s="a|b-c|d"
awk -v RS='[-|]' 'NR==3{$0="z"} {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' <<< "$s"

a|b-z|d
```

Alternatively you can use `sed`:

```
s="a|b-c|d"
sed -E 's/^(([^|-]+[|-]){2})[^|-]+/\1z/' <<< "$s"

a|b-z|d
```

Comment: nice usage of `RT`!

Comment: I think you could optimize sed solution as  `sed -E 's/^(([^|-]+[|-]){2})[^|-]+/\1z/' <<< "$s"` ... captures first two fields along with separators and then replaces third field without bothering what lies beyond and incl. third separator...

Answer (score 0):

Since you clearly don't need to work the fields, just process $0 other ways, like below with `sub`:

```
$ echo "a|b-c|d" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[|-]"} {sub(/c/,"z")}1'
a|b-z|d
```

Comment: The values I took in the example are dummy ones. A simple `sub` would not work in a generic case where, for example you set `$3=$1$2` (and not a hardcoded value).

Comment: So I figured but decided to leave this as a remainder for the future generations of Masters of Archaic Languages.