# extract a numeric substring and add value to it

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string like `1001.2001.3001.5001.6001` or `1001-2001-3001-5001-6001`. How to extract the 4th string i.e., `5001`, add a value like `121` to it and put it back in the same string. The output should be like `1001.2001.3001.5122.6001` or `1001-2001-3001-5122-6001`. I have to achieve this in Linux bash scripting.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: You should probably check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428118/6381711).

Comment: The bottleneck here is that you've multiple delims.This [\[ answer \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39326264/1620779) nicely points a workaround provided you've GNU awk

Comment: Without any attempt it would seem like you just want someone else to do the work for you.  This could all be done with simple bash substitution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the field separator can either be `.` or `-`, then do something like

```
echo "1001.2001.3001.5001.6001" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[.-]";OFS="-"}{$4+=121}1'
1001-2001-3001-5122-6001
```

However, if you need to match the regex `FS` or field separator with `OFS` then you need to have `gawk` installed

```
echo "1001.2001.3001.5001.6001" |
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[.-]"}{split($0,a,FS,seps)}{$4+=121;OFS=seps[1]}1'
1001.2001.3001.5122.6001
```

Comment: @hmedia1 shame?? Why don't you consider this as a possible solution? And I have not even claimed this to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$1 
if [[ $(echo $str | grep '\.'  | wc -l) == 1 ]]
then
   str1=$(echo $str |  cut -d '.' -f 1,2,3)
   str2=$(echo $str | cut -d '.' -f 4 | awk {'print $1+121'})
   str3=$(echo $str |  cut -d '.' -f 5)
   echo $str1.$str2.$str3

elif [[ $(echo $str | grep - | wc -l) == 1 ]]
then
    str1=$(echo $str |  cut -d '-' -f 1,2,3)
    str2=$(echo $str | cut -d '-' -f 4 | awk {'print $1+121'})
    str3=$(echo $str |  cut -d '-' -f 5) 
    echo $str1-$str2-$str3
else
    echo "do nothing"
fi
```

Pass a string as parameter

Answer (score 1):

No pipes, no forks, no cutting, no awking, just plain POSIX shell:

```
$ s=1001.2001.3001.5001.6001
$ oldIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=.-
$ set -- $s
$ case $s in
> (*.*) echo "$1.$2.$3.$(($4 + 121)).$5";;
> (*-*) echo "$1-$2-$3-$(($4 + 121))-$5";;
> esac
1001.2001.3001.5122.6001
$ IFS=$oldIFS
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's anything wrong, please give me a chance for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

## One liner

```
value=121 ; str='1001.2001.3001.5001.6001' ; token="$(echo "$str" | cut -f 4 -d '.')" ; newtoken=$(( $token + $value )) ; newstr="$(echo "$str" | sed -e "s/$token/$newtoken/g" | tr '.' '-')" ; echo "$newstr"
```

Breakdown:

```
value=121                                            # <- Increment
str='1001.2001.3001.5001.6001'                       # <- Initial String
token="$(echo "$str" | cut -f 4 -d '.')"             # <- Extract the 4th field with . sep
newtoken=$(( $token + $value ))                      # <- Add value and save to $newtoken
newstr="$(echo "$str" \
| sed -e "s/$token/$newtoken/g" \
| tr '.' '-')"                                       # <- Replace 4th field with $newtoken
                                                     #    and translate "." to "-"
echo "$newstr"                                       # <- Echo new string
```

Works in:

- Bash
- sh
- FreeBSD
- Busybox

Using out of the box tools

Answer (score -1):

Though resetting the argument list with the values is probably the preferred way, or by setting `IFS` to the *delimiter* and reading the values into an array and adding the desired value to the array index at issue, you can also do it with a simple loop to look for the *delimiters* and continually skipping characters until the desired segment is found (`4` in you case -- when the delimiter count is `3`). Then simply appending the digit at each *array index* until your next delimiter is found will give you the base value. Simply adding your desired `121` to the completed number completes the script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

str=${1:-"1001.2001.3001.5001.6001"}    ## string
ele=${2:-4}     ## element to add value to [1, 2, 3, ...]
add=${3:-121}   ## value to add to element
cnt=0           ## flag to track delimiters found
num=

## for each character in str
for ((i = 0; i < ${#str}; i++))
do
    if [ "${str:$i:1}" = '.' -o "${str:$i:1}" = '-' ]   ## is it '.' or '-'
    then
        (( cnt++ ))                 ## increment count
        (( cnt == ele )) && break   ## if equal to ele, break

    ## check each char is a valid digit 0-9
    elif [ "0" -le "${str:$i:1}" -a "${str:$4i:1}" -le "9" ]
    then
        (( cnt == (ele - 1) )) || continue  ## it not one of interest, continue
        num="$num${str:$i:1}"               ## append digit to num
    fi
done

((num += add))  ## add the amount to num

printf "num: %d\n" $num     ## print results
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash parsenum.sh
num: 5122

$ bash parsenum.sh "1001.2001.3001.5001.6001" 2
num: 2122

$ bash parsenum.sh "1001.2001.3001.5001.6001" 2 221
num: 2222
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.